# Using BeautifulSoup4 to return data in a table buried very far down a tree

Tags: python, html, css, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the high and low weather data from the following page (and then several others once this works): https://www.wunderground.com/history/monthly/us/ma/east-boston/KBOS/date/1982-1

The selector for the first high is: `#inner-content > div.region-content-main > div.row > div:nth-child(5) > div:nth-child(1) > div > lib-city-history-observation > div > div.observation-table.ng-star-inserted > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2) > table > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(1)`

The below returns data, but doesn't go far enough down the tree (because after that, it no longer works, as explained below):

```
import requests, bs4

url = (f"https://www.wunderground.com/history/monthly/us/ma/east-boston/KBOS/date/1982-1")

res = requests.get(url)
try:
    res.raise_for_status()
except Exception:
    print('no data')
else:
    page = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')

temps = page.search('div > div > div > div > div > lib-city-history-observation')
```

If I go beyond the `lib-city-history-observation` it no longer captures the right data. The issue is it needs to select the second sibling after lib, then continue down that branch. I haven't found a way that works.

I've also tried searching for the final element with `page.find_all('td', {'class': 'ng-star-inserted'})`, but that turns up nothing, rather than the expected temperature string. Please help! (Very much a BS4 rookie, so please be kind and explain it to me as if I were 5!)

Comment: Maybe look into using an XPath

Comment: Be aware that the page may be modified by JavaScript code. If so, other tools like Selenium may be necessary.

Comment: I'm not grasping what 'the second sibling after lib' means as it looks as though the interesting data (ie in that table) is all contained within lib-....

Comment: @AHaworth there are two branches after lib, and it's the second branch that contains the data I want, but I don't know how to tell BS to look there. Any additional tags after "lib" go down that first branch to a dead end.

Comment: Simple "requests" won't work here as you can check the content of the defined variable "page" does not contain the desired data. As @MichaelButscher rightly mentioned the page gets loaded/modified as we interact with it. Therefore, you can try using selenium.

Answer (score 1):

Raw data of observations is loaded via api and processed before rendered as table in the browser. You could use `selenium` to mimic the same behavior or operate with the raw data.

In second case simply request the api and work with the hourly data:

```
requests.get('https://api.weather.com/v1/location/KBOS:9:US/observations/historical.json?apiKey=e1f10a1e78da46f5b10a1e78da96f525&units=e&startDate=19820101&endDate=19820131').json()['observations']
```

###### Selenium example

Just to point in a direction, because OP is missing details to expected output.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

url = 'https://www.wunderground.com/history/monthly/us/ma/east-boston/KBOS/date/1982-1'

driver.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)
for row in soup.select('table[aria-labelledby="History days"] tbody table'):
    print(list(row.stripped_strings))
```

##### Output

```
['Jan', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31', '1']
['Max', 'Avg', 'Min', '41', '28.0', '0', '36', '31.4', '22', '31', '21.6', '0', '55', '26.8', '0', '54', '37.6', '0', '43', '34.8', '28', '43', '33.1', '0', '31', '21.4', '0', '30', '20.4', '0', '22', '11.3', '0', '14', '7.2', '0', '15', '9.0', '3', '22', '15.2', '0', '24', '16.7', '0', '26', '20.8', '0', '34', '16.7', '0', '31', '8.4', '2', '14', '5.8', '-2', '22', '14.3', '8', '35', '19.1', '0', '22', '13.9', '9', '15', '7.7', '2', '38', '13.6', '0', '33', '17.6', '0', '20', '16.0', '11', '19', '13.5', '9', '23', '11.5', '1', '36', '24.6', '12', '35', '32.0', '29', '42', '27.5', '0', '42', '34.1', '0', '34', '17.0', '0']
['Max', 'Avg', 'Min', '39', '24.4', '0', '33', '13.4', '0', '24', '10.4', '0', '53', '24.2', '0', '48', '19.0', '0', '33', '16.1', '0', '34', '23.6', '0', '20', '5.3', '-3', '19', '9.4', '0', '11', '-7.6', '-18', '0', '-10.1', '-17', '-7', '-15.0', '-18', '17', '-2.6', '-15', '20', '13.7', '0', '20', '11.3', '0', '31', '10.9', '0', '21', '-13.0', '-25', '-10', '-17.5', '-24', '-1', '-6.6', '-11', '20', '11.3', '0', '3', '-6.6', '-14', '-15', '-17.0', '-20', '37', '5.4', '-19', '29', '9.0', '-5', '-2', '-5.1', '-8', '3', '-4.9', '-10', '-1', '-7.6', '-15', '26', '12.5', '-4', '21', '15.4', '12', '35', '20.2', '0', '31', '21.9', '0', '0', '0.0', '0']
['Max', 'Avg', 'Min', '93', '61.5', '0', '89', '51.9', '35', '73', '53.1', '0', '97', '59.3', '0', '80', '44.8', '0', '70', '58.8', '35', '89', '62.2', '0', '75', '45.6', '0', '85', '46.0', '0', '71', '40.5', '0', '46', '31.9', '0', '44', '33.5', '25', '89', '45.5', '0', '92', '68.5', '0', '92', '61.1', '0', '96', '53.8', '0', '69', '38.3', '26', '40', '33.7', '29', '51', '39.8', '25', '88', '53.6', '0', '51', '40.4', '27', '41', '32.1', '25', '100', '44.9', '0', '96', '44.7', '0', '53', '39.7', '32', '59', '44.5', '36', '51', '42.6', '35', '75', '60.5', '39', '67', '51.3', '39', '79', '63.6', '0', '92', '63.9', '0', '92', '46.0', '0']
['Max', 'Avg', 'Min', '23', '15.0', '9', '23', '18.2', '13', '15', '7.0', '2', '37', '15.9', '3', '26', '21.6', '17', '18', '12.4', '9', '17', '9.6', '5', '28', '17.2', '9', '17', '11.6', '3', '26', '19.1', '12', '23', '17.8', '12', '23', '16.4', '10', '14', '7.4', '3', '20', '15.0', '10', '24', '19.2', '13', '28', '12.0', '6', '26', '20.6', '16', '22', '16.2', '10', '16', '10.3', '2', '16', '10.2', '0', '16', '12.5', '7', '17', '12.9', '9', '17', '9.7', '5', '22', '13.5', '3', '26', '17.8', '9', '17', '11.4', '1', '16', '11.0', '5', '25', '13.9', '5', '22', '16.2', '12', '16', '10.8', '3', '23', '14.1', '5', '22', '21.5', '21']
['Max', 'Avg', 'Min', '30.3', '29.9', '29.7', '30.4', '30.1', '29.8', '30.4', '30.4', '30.4', '30.4', '29.9', '29.3', '30.0', '29.6', '29.3', '30.1', '30.0', '29.8', '29.9', '29.8', '29.8', '30.0', '29.9', '29.9', '29.9', '29.5', '29.3', '29.7', '29.5', '29.3', '29.7', '29.6', '29.5', '30.2', '30.0', '29.7', '30.3', '30.2', '30.0', '29.9', '29.6', '29.3', '29.8', '29.4', '29.1', '30.0', '29.8', '29.6', '30.1', '29.9', '29.6', '30.3', '30.2', '30.1', '30.3', '30.3', '30.2', '30.2', '30.1', '30.0', '30.4', '30.3', '30.2', '30.7', '30.6', '30.4', '30.7', '30.1', '29.4', '29.6', '29.4', '29.2', '29.9', '29.7', '29.6', '30.2', '30.0', '29.9', '30.3', '30.3', '30.2', '30.3', '30.1', '29.9', '30.4', '30.2', '30.0', '30.4', '30.2', '30.0', '30.2', '30.1', '29.9', '30.0', '30.0', '30.0']
['Total', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00']
```